# What is the correct syntax for a Flyway connection string to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2012, connection-string, flyway

Running SQL Server 2012 Express on a remote machine, trying to get Flyway up and running. I have a database on `pcesqldev.pce.local` called `Hawk` (`dbo.Hawk`, if that matters) that I want to connect to, and the template from the config file looks like this:

```
SQL Server        : jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>/<database>
```

Note, this is different from other jdbc connection strings I have used with other products - most of them do not include the jtds portion and do include the instance name.

Here's a few connection strings that I have tried, all of which failed:

- ```
  flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pcesqldev.pce.local:1433/Hawk
  ```

  > Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
- ```
  flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pcesqldev.pce.local\SQLEXPRESS:1433/Hawk
  ```

  > Unknown server host name 'pcesqldev.pce.local\SQLEXPRESS'
- ```
  flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pcesqldev.pce.local/SQLEXPRESS:1433/Hawk
  ```

  > Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
- ```
  flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pcesqldev.pce.local:1433/SQLEXPRESS\Hawk
  ```

  > Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect

What am I missing? There must be something obvious, but I can't see it.

Before anybody asks, yes we do have TCP access to the database enabled and it is using port 1433.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one got me, and there was not many answers out there on how to format a connection string with an instance name.

Here's what worked for me:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<host>:<port>/<database>;instance=<instance_name>
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'm in a crunch to get this release done but will try your suggestion as soon as I get a break and let you know how it works.

Comment: How can we pass query params like jdbc:mariadb:aurora://myHost/db?socketTimeout=0

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone's problems, the correct connection string is as follows:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME:1433/DB_NAME
```

It took me some time to realize that, but maybe it will be helpful for someone :)

Answer (score 3):

This did my head in for a bit.

The connection string which I used was this (passed as parameters to flyway on the commandline).

Note also that the mydatabasename needed to already exist.

```
./flyway migrate -url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/mydatabasename -user=myuser -password=mypassword -baselineVersion=269 -baselineDescription="Base version" -outOfOrder=true -baselineOnMigrate=
```

A piece that was missing though was that I wasn't running SQL Server Browser and possibly didn't have TCP set up correctly:

From the SQL Server section [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/contribute/code/database).
After the installation is complete, enable TCP/IP:

Launch the Sql Server Configuration Manager
Go to SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
Enable TCP/IP
TCP/IP Properties -> IP Addresses -> IPAll
TCP Dynamic Ports: blank
TCP Port: 1433
Then enable remote access:

Launch the Sql Server Configuration Manager
SQL Server Services -> SQL Server Browser -> Properties -> Service Tab
Start Mode: Automatic
OK
SQL Server Browser -> Start
SQL Server -> Restart

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved starting the service "SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)"

Steps:

- Windows + R -> It'll open "Run" window
- Type "services.msc" without double quotes ("")
- Search for SQL Server Agent service
- Right click over "SQL Server Agent" and go to Properties
- Change "Startup type" to "Automatic" and apply the configuration
- After clicked over "Apply" button, it'll enable "Start" button, click over this button
- After the service has been started, try to execute flyway again

[image: Image Example]